# Cancel "tail -f" if the file hasn't changed for N seconds?

Tags: bash, timeout, tail

I am debugging an application, that has a long running time and produces only a logfile as reliably complete output, so usually I use `tail -f` to monitor the output. Since it also requires some specific setup of the environment variables, I have wrapped the whole invocation, including `tail -f LOGFILE &`, into a bash script.

However, this creates a `tail` process that won't be terminated automatically and will remain running. Cleanup with `trap` leads to complicated code, once there is more than a single cleanup task, and there is no obvious way to account for all ways the script may be terminated.

Using the `timeout` command, I could limit `tail -f` to terminate after a fixed total time, but that will break cases, where it is SUPPOSED to run longer.

So I was wondering, if there is a way to limit `tail -f` such that it terminates, if the followed file doesn't change for a specified amount of time.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** The subsequent script worked for me when executed on its own, but in some instances, the tail process would not terminate regardless. It isn't entirely clear, whether `tail -f` detects that process it is piping to has terminated.

---

Lacking a builtin solution, a stdout based timeout can be produced in bash, exploiting that `tail` will terminate, if it's stdout is closed.

```
# Usage: withTimeout TIMEOUT COMMAND [ARGS ...]
# Execute COMMAND. Terminate, if it hasn't produced new output in TIMEOUT seconds.
# Depending on the platform, TIMEOUT may be fractional. See `help read`.
withTimeout () {
    local timeout="$1"; shift 1
    "$@" | while IFS= read -r -t "${timeout}" line || return 0; do 
        printf "%s\n" "$line"
    done
}

withTimeout 2 tail -f LOGFILE &
```

Note that `tail` may resort to polling the file once per second, if it cannot use inotify. If faster output is needed the `-s` option can be supplied.